# text-overflow : ellipsis fails intermittently in a single load while using IE 11

Tags: html, css

```css
.show-ellipsis {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row show-ellipsis">
    {{record.bodyName}}
  </div>
</div>
```

I have an application that support IE 9 to IE 11. The ellipsis style that I have applied at  level is given in the below snippet. This  is inside an ng-repeat. The ellipsis shows up for some of the rows and does not show for some. I also checked in database to see if the text coming from database has any html tags like br 
 inside it, but it does not. I have also attached a screenshot for more clarity. Please help  [please click to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIH86.png)

Comment: How big is the box that is creating the problem? It's possible that the child element actually extends farther than the parent container.

Comment: there is no box actually, it just text displayed inside <div> I use angularjs. hope this answers the question

Comment: Can you post the HTML?

Comment: added the HTML but not sure it will help. show-ellipsis is the class that is causing the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure whats causing the text-overflow:ellipsis not work in IE11 for some of text. I am now using ng-class to load the same style and it works. the HTMl looks like this now

```js
record.showEllipsis = 'show-ellipsis';
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div ng-class="record.showEllipsis">
    {{record.bodyName}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are working in murky waters here. After checking [Caniuse.com for text-overflow](http://caniuse.com/#feat=text-overflow) it seems that text-overflow is not fully supported by IE versions under 11.

Also, the section of caniuse labeled "known issues" may help you as well:

- Does not work in IE8 and IE9 on `<input type="text">`
- Some Samsung-based browsers, have a bug with overflowing text when ellipsis is set and if text-rendering is not auto.
- Does not work on select elements work in Chrome and IE, only Firefox.

Comment: I am forcing the style using !important for all three properties. It still does not work. in dev tool if I uncheck and check the overflow property, it works correctly. the weird thing is it works for few rows and does not work for few.